# Perl / Python Quick Reference?

Tags: python, perl

I am reasonably fluent in writing perl / python scripts, but still while writing code, I find myself frequently using google to look up the exact order of operands of some built-in function, or the exact name of some feature I know exists. While google works reasonably well, it does take some searching, and about half the time, the reference page doesn't have the right examples that I need.

Does anyone know of any good quick reference for perl or python that would have most of the important usage information and basic examples in one place ? Should I make my own ? Or do most people use IDEs and don't need this kind of help ? (I use vim, BTW).

Thanks!

Comment: For Python what's wrong with [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/)?

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org  I've configured my browser with shortcuts so I can type "perldoc perlop" in the URL bar.  Actually, I can't imagine developing in Perl without access to the POD, and to search.cpan.org.

Comment: @Ben, nothing wrong, but I feel I need more examples some of the time to clarify how to use things. I don't have an example doc-page handy.

Comment: There is some books free to read too: https://www.google.com/search?q=perl+oreally

Answer (score 7):

For Perl, it's `perldoc`

```
perldoc Module::Name  # display docs for Module::Name
perldoc -f substr     # display docs for substr()
perldoc -Q parse      # search the FAQ for "parse"
perldoc -v %+         # display docs for special variable %+
perldoc perlcheat     # overview of most important syntax
perldoc perl          # overview of interesting perldoc pages
```

Comment: You can do the same thing with `pydoc`:  `pydoc collections.OrderedDict`

Comment: There are tools / modules such as `perlfind` that automatically supplies correct parameter to `perldoc`, see http://p3rl.org/App::perlfind

Answer (score 7):

Most **well written** python code should have docstrings that provide information on modules and functions simply by entering *help* into the interpreter.

```
>>> help(str)
>>> (lots of helpful output here!)
```

Answer (score 3):

For perl, if you want something at your elbow you can't do better than the [Perl Reference Guide / Perl Pocket Reference](http://www.vromans.org/johan/perlref.html) by Johan Vromans. Print out [the PDF](http://www.squirrel.nl/pub/perlref-5.004.1.pdf) and staple it into a booklet, or just pick it up at your local bookstore. (Let's face it, a one-page quick reference is not nearly enough for perl).

It got me through many years of perl use... till I switched to python :-)

For python, incidentally, I just google the docs on [docs.python.org](http://docs.python.org/)-- or here on stackoverflow; python's syntax being what it is, when I look something up I'm usually after a more in-depth description than you can get out of a quick-reference card.